# How can I limit div movement inside another div?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a moveable and resizable div with JavaScript. This div is in another div element.

What I want to do is to set the moveable limit of the div to the current border of this outer div.

So that it is only possible to move the div inside of the other div. Here is what I have so far:

```js
let isResizing = false;
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".textbox");
for (let el of elements) {
  el.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);

  function mouseDown(e) {

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);

    let prevX = e.clientX;
    let prevY = e.clientY;

    function mouseMove(e) {
      if (!isResizing) {
        let newX = prevX - e.clientX;
        let newY = prevY - e.clientY;

        const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        el.style.left = rect.left - newX + "px";
        el.style.top = rect.top - newY + "px";

        prevX = e.clientX;
        prevY = e.clientY;
      }
    }

    function mouseUp() {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.horizbox {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 65%;
  color: black;

  /* demo only */
  height: 120px;
  background: black;
}

.textbox {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizbox">
  <div class="textbox">
    <div class="resizer ne"></div>
    <div class="resizer nw"></div>
    <div class="resizer sw"></div>
    <div class="resizer se"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome. "Is it possible" isn't a great question for SO. It's not specific enough. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Then, it's a matter of comparing the sides of your inner element to the sides of the outer element. Many libraries have tackled this already, so you might look at some of them.

Comment: Well, you have code that moves the box, right? And you are getting the coordinates of the box. So if the left or top of those coordinates are outside of the box defined by its container, don't set the corresponding style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some small modifications to achieve what you want:

```js
let isResizing = false;
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".textbox");
for (let el of elements) {
  el.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown);

  function mouseDown(e) {

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);

    let prevX = e.clientX;
    let prevY = e.clientY;

    function mouseMove(e) {
      if (!isResizing) {
        let newX = prevX - e.clientX;
        let newY = prevY - e.clientY;
        
        const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        
        /* new */
        const bounds = el.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
        const x = Math.min(
          Math.max(bounds.left, rect.left - newX), bounds.right - rect.width
        ),    y = Math.min(
          Math.max(bounds.top, rect.top - newY), bounds.bottom - rect.height
        );
        /**/
        
        el.style.left = `${x}px`;
        el.style.top = `${y}px`;
        prevX = e.clientX;
        prevY = e.clientY;
      }
    }

    function mouseUp() {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.horizbox {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 65%;
  color: black;

  /* demo only */
  height: 120px;
  background: black;
}

.textbox {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizbox">
  <div class="textbox">
    <div class="resizer ne"></div>
    <div class="resizer nw"></div>
    <div class="resizer sw"></div>
    <div class="resizer se"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**:

Get the bounding box (const `bounds`) of the outer container and use js `min, max`-methods to keep the new x and y values inside the bounds.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what i was looking for :D

Comment: Sorry but I still got a question. The div is also resizable. I can resize it much larger than the parent div "horizbox". Can i do this also with he js min, max method?